# Handling IDisposable in failed initializer or constructor

Tags: .net, constructor, idisposable

Is there any nice pattern in .Net for ensuring that `IDisposable` fields owned by an object will get disposed if an exception is thrown during construction, possibly during a field initializer?  The only way to surround field initializers in a Try/Catch block is if the block is outside the call to the constructor, which will make it rather difficult for cleanup code to properly dispose of anything.

The only approach I can figure would be to the object inherit from a base class whose constructor takes something like an array of `IDisposable`, and sets the first item in that array to point to itself.  All constructors the descendant classes should be Private or Protected, and include that parameter.  Instantiation should be via factory methods, which will declare an array of one `IDisposable` and pass it to the appropriate constructor.  If the constructor fails, the factory method will have a reference to the partially-constructed object, which it can then dispose (the dispose method must, of course, be prepared to accept the possibility that the object may not be fully constructed).

The approach could be extended by having the object keep a list of iDisposable objects it creates, to allow the objects to be cleaned up without having to explicitly dispose each one; such a list would be useful in conjunction with the factory-method-calls-dispose approach, but is largely orthogonal to it.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've come up with a pattern that seems pretty good.  It's inspired by an someone posted on CodeProject.com--using a list to keep track of disposables; raiiBase(of T) is a base class suitable for any class whose constructor takes a single parameter.  The class constructor must be protected, and construction must be done via factory method.  The static makeRaii() constructor takes a delegate to a factory function, which must accept a Stack(of iDisposable) along with a parameter of the class's expected type.  A sample usage:

```
Public Class RaiiTest
    Inherits raiiBase(Of String)
    Dim thing1 As testDisposable = RAII(New testDisposable("Moe " & creationParam, "a"))
    Dim thing2 As testDisposable = RAII(New testDisposable("Larry " & creationParam, "b"))
    Dim thing3 As testDisposable = RAII(New testDisposable("Shemp " & creationParam, "c"))
    Dim thing4 As testDisposable = RAII(New testDisposable("Curly " & creationParam, "d"))

    Protected Sub New(ByVal dispList As Stack(Of IDisposable), ByVal newName As String)
        MyBase.New(dispList, newName)
    End Sub

    Private Shared Function _newRaiiTest(ByVal dispList As Stack(Of IDisposable), ByVal theName As String) As RaiiTest
        Return New RaiiTest(dispList, theName)
    End Function

    Public Shared Function newRaiiTest(ByVal theName As String) As RaiiTest
        Return makeRaii(Of RaiiTest)(AddressOf _newRaiiTest, theName)
    End Function

    Shared Sub test(ByVal st As String)
        Try
            Using it As RaiiTest = newRaiiTest(st)
                Debug.Print("Now using object")
            End Using
            Debug.Print("No exceptions thrown")
        Catch ex As raiiException
            Debug.Print("Output exception: " & ex.Message)
            If ex.InnerException IsNot Nothing Then Debug.Print("Inner exception: " & ex.InnerException.Message)
            For Each exx As Exception In ex.DisposalExceptions
                Debug.Print("Disposal exception: " & exx.Message)
            Next
        Catch ex As Exception
            Debug.Print("Misc. exception: " & ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub
End Class
```

Since raiiTest inherits raiiBase(of String), to create a class instance, call newRaiiTest with a string parameter.  RAII() is a generic function that will register its argument as an iDisposable that will need cleaning up, and then return it.  All registered disposables will be Disposed when either Dispose is called on the main object, or when an exception is thrown in the construction of the main object.

Here's the riaaBase class:

```
Option Strict On
Class raiiException
    Inherits Exception
    ReadOnly _DisposalExceptions() As Exception
    Sub New(ByVal message As String, ByVal InnerException As Exception, ByVal allInnerExceptions As Exception())
        MyBase.New(message, InnerException)
        _DisposalExceptions = allInnerExceptions
    End Sub
    Public Overridable ReadOnly Property DisposalExceptions() As Exception()
        Get
            Return _DisposalExceptions
        End Get
    End Property
End Class

Public Class raiiBase(Of T)
    Implements IDisposable

    Protected raiiList As Stack(Of IDisposable)
    Protected creationParam As T
    Delegate Function raiiFactory(Of TT As raiiBase(Of T))(ByVal theList As Stack(Of IDisposable), ByVal theParam As T) As TT

    Shared Function CopyFirstParamToSecondAndReturnFalse(Of TT)(ByVal P1 As TT, ByRef P2 As TT) As Boolean
        P2 = P1
        Return False
    End Function

    Shared Function makeRaii(Of TT As raiiBase(Of T))(ByVal theFactory As raiiFactory(Of TT), ByVal theParam As T) As TT
        Dim dispList As New Stack(Of IDisposable)
        Dim constructionFailureException As Exception = Nothing
        Try
            Return theFactory(dispList, theParam)
        Catch ex As Exception When CopyFirstParamToSecondAndReturnFalse(ex, constructionFailureException)
            ' The above statement let us find out what exception occurred without having to catch and rethrow
            Throw ' Should never happen, since we should have returned false above
        Finally
            If constructionFailureException IsNot Nothing Then
                zapList(dispList, constructionFailureException)
            End If
        End Try
    End Function

    Protected Sub New(ByVal DispList As Stack(Of IDisposable), ByVal Params As T)
        Me.raiiList = DispList
        Me.creationParam = Params
    End Sub

    Public Shared Sub zapList(ByVal dispList As IEnumerable(Of IDisposable), ByVal triggerEx As Exception)
        Using theEnum As IEnumerator(Of IDisposable) = dispList.GetEnumerator
            Try
                While theEnum.MoveNext
                    theEnum.Current.Dispose()
                End While
            Catch ex As Exception
                Dim exList As New List(Of Exception)
                exList.Add(ex)
                While theEnum.MoveNext
                    Try
                        theEnum.Current.Dispose()
                    Catch ex2 As Exception
                        exList.Add(ex2)
                    End Try
                End While
                Throw New raiiException("RAII failure", triggerEx, exList.ToArray)
            End Try
        End Using
    End Sub

    Function RAII(Of U As IDisposable)(ByVal Thing As U) As U
        raiiList.Push(Thing)
        Return Thing
    End Function

    Shared Sub zap(ByVal Thing As IDisposable)
        If Thing IsNot Nothing Then Thing.Dispose()
    End Sub

    Private raiiBaseDisposeFlag As Integer = 0 ' To detect redundant calls

    ' IDisposable
    Protected Overridable Sub Dispose(ByVal disposing As Boolean)
        If disposing AndAlso Threading.Interlocked.Exchange(raiiBaseDisposeFlag, 1) = 0 Then
            zapList(raiiList, Nothing)
        End If
    End Sub

#Region " IDisposable Support "
    ' This code added by Visual Basic to correctly implement the disposable pattern.
    Public Sub Dispose() Implements IDisposable.Dispose
        ' Do not change this code.  Put cleanup code in Dispose(ByVal disposing As Boolean) above.
        Dispose(True)
        GC.SuppressFinalize(Me)
    End Sub
#End Region

End Class
```

Note that a custom exception type will be thrown if disposal fails for any or all of the registered disposable objects.  InnerException will indicate whether the constructor failed; to see which disposer(s) failed, check DisposalExceptions.

Answer (score 12):

You should catch any exceptions in the constructor, then dispose of your child objects, then rethrow the original exception (or a new exception that provides additional information).

```
public class SomethingDisposable : IDisposable
{
  System.Diagnostics.Process disposableProcess;
  public SomethingDisposable()
  {
    try
    {
      disposableProcess = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
      // Will throw an exception because I didn't tell it what to start
      disposableProcess.Start();
    }
    catch
    {
      this.Dispose();
      throw;
    }
  }

  public void Dispose()
  {
    if (disposableProcess != null)
    {
      disposableProcess.Dispose();
      disposableProcess = null;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Is there any way to catch exceptions in initializers (e.g. "Font myFont = New Font("Arial", ...whatever...);")?  In many cases, it's far more convenient to create objects when they're defined than to define them in one place and then create them somewhere else.

Comment: @supercat: Not that I'm aware of.  I agree with the simplicity that you seek, but in this case being robust is more important.

Comment: +1 but I prefer *not* to call `Dispose` in the constructor, because if you implement the so-called canonical `IDisposable` pattern then you might end up with a virtual call during the constructor call (via `protected void Dispose(bool disposing)`).

Answer (score 1):

Holding on to a partially constructed object sounds dangerous to me, if it would even work.  I wouldn't use initializers or a ctor to handle this.

How about if instead, you use an object factory (not quite the same as a class factory) to create your object.

The constructor of your object would not be responsible for creating the IDisposable objects that it owns.  Instead, the factory would create each IDisposable and it would call the constructor on your owner object.  The factory would then set the appropriate members in the owner object to the disposable objects that were created.

pseudocode:

```
public superobject CreateSuperObject()
{
   IDisposable[] members = new IDisposable[n]
   try
     SuperObject o = new SuperObject()
     // init the iDisposable members, add each to the array, (you will probably also nee
     o.DisposableMember1 = new somethingdisposeable();
     members[0] = o.DisposeableMember1

     return o;
   catch
      // loop through the members array, disposing where not null
      // throw a new exception??
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As strange as it may seem, but it looks that GC is still calling destructor for IDisposable objects, even if they throw exception in constructor! :)

```
using (crazy = new MyDisposable()) <-- constructor throws
{
} <-- dispose wont get called

... somewhen in far future
~MyDisposable() <-- GC kicks in.
```

If you were smart enough to use example from msdn, where they called Dispose(false) from destructor - well - you just failed! :)

Comment: Some IDisposable objects will behave acceptably even if they are not disposed, because a finalizer will fire in acceptably-timely fashion to clean them up.  There are other situations, however, were a failure to properly Dispose an object can cause a major memory leak of indefinite duration (e.g. an event subscriber which has references to many other objects and subscribes to an event from a long-lived object uses Dispose to unsubscribe that event.  If dispose doesn't fire, neither that object, nor any to which it holds a reference, can be collected until the long-lived object dies.)

Comment: In vb.net, I've come up with a pattern for disposable objects which allows object declaration, initialization, and cleanup, to be handled on a single line (see below).  It requires that field initializers be run after the base constructor, though, and is thus probably not adaptable to C#.

Answer (score -2):

In C# you would use 'using':

```
        using(DisposableObject obj = new DisposableObject()) {
        }
```

VB also has a Using...End Using construct.
When using these the Dispose method is guaranteed to be called, even in the event of an exception.  You can release any resources created by the initializers (or the constructor) in the Dispose method.

Comment: -1 This doesn't work if the constructor throws an exception.  The new object is never returned, so there is nothing to call Dispose on.